# Positional Index In python?

Tags: python

am able to create an inverted index but I cannot quite implement a positional index. Positional index has a format of `[doc_ID, pos_1, pos_2, ...]`

here doc_ID indicate which document the word appears in and which position it appears in that document.

Ex. `index = positional_index(['a','b','a'], ['a','c']])`
when user  enters `index['a']` it will return `[[0,0,2], [1,0]]`

The following code is for the mentioned inverted index. I have no idea what else to add to make it positional index:

```
def positional index(tokens):
    d = defaultdict(lambda:[])

    for docID, t_list in enumerate(tokens):
        for t in t_list:
            d[t].append(docID)

return d
```

All help would be much appreciated.

Comment: whats the logic behind `[[0,0,2], [1,0]]` for index of `a` ? your explain is unclear !

Comment: 'a' is in document 0 and positions 0 and 2 as well as document 1 position 0. Basically first number is which [ ] it is in starting with 0 and the rest after wards is where in the [ ] does the "word" (this case 'a') exists...this also starts with zero

Comment: is `__getitem__` style access (i.e. `index['a']`) mandatory? if not then Kasra AD's answer is nice

Comment: @Anentropic, that only stores a single index, you would have to call and create a list for every single item you wanted to check where you only need create a dict once

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function :

```
>>> def find_index(l,elem) :
...   return [[i]+[t for t,k in enumerate(j) if k==elem] for i,j in enumerate(l)]
... 
>>> find_index(l,'a')
[[0, 0, 2], [1, 0]]
```

All stuff that you need here is using `enumerate` within two list comprehension .

Answer (score 1):

Using your own code you just need to add the indexes for each element and the docID using a set to avoid repeated keys:

```
def positional_index(tokens):
    d = defaultdict(lambda:[])
    for docID, sub_l in enumerate(tokens):
        for t in set(sub_l):
            d[t].append([docID] + [ind for ind, ele in enumerate(sub_l) if ele == t])
    return d

In [9]: index=  positional_index([['a','b','a'], ['a','c']])

In [10]: index["a"]
Out[10]: [[0, 0, 2], [1, 0]]
In [11]: index["b"]
Out[11]: [[0, 1]]

In [12]: index["c"]
Out[12]: [[1, 1]]
```

Comment: Is `defaultdict(lambda:[])` different than `defaultdict(list)`?

Comment: @IceArdor, very little difference here , normally you would use it when you were doing something like `defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))`

Comment: It does actually seem slightly more efficient using a lambda using python 2 though